# What is the easiest way to load external data to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a simple chrome extension - something like a personal dictionary that will highlight specific words on webpages - I want to however store the list of words on external server, so I can update it anytime. I want it to be separate from script so I can give just a list of words for someone to update it, and they do not mess up the script itself

for now I am trying with a simple data.js on external server:

```
 infoTextD = [ 'car', 'cat', 'dog' ];
```

the content.js looks like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/Curiosit/Curiosit/master/data.js',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "script",
        success: function () {
var d = infoTextD;
         },
    error: function () {
        // handle errors
    }
});
```

This produces an error in console: infoTextD is not defined. I understand then that this ajax include does not pass variables to the main script??

How I can load a variable array from external server to chrome extension then?

PS.
My manifest :

```
            {
            "manifest_version": 2,
              "name": "a",
              "description": "a ",
                "version": "0.1",
                 "content_scripts": [
                    {
                        "matches": [
                    "<all_urls>"
                        ],
                        "js": [
                        "jquery-2.2.0.js",

                            "content.js"

                        ],
                        "run_at": "document_end"
                    }
                ],
                  "background": {
                "page": "popup.html"
              },
                "browser_action": {
               "default_icon": "icon.png",
               "default_popup": "popup.html"
               },
                 "permissions": [
               "activeTab",
               "http://*/",
                  "https://*/"

               ]

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things :

- You should serve the external data as json (e.g : `['car', 'cat', 'dog']` only, without the `infoTextD = ...`)
- You then access the returned data from the success callback

E.g :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/Curiosit/Curiosit/master/data.json',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (infoTextD) {
        console.log(infoTextD);
    },
    error: function () {
        // handle errors
    }
});
```